# howto properly rails api rspec json test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, rspec

I've got `UsersController`

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render json: @user, status: :created
  else
    render json: @user, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

I need to test this create action with RSPec. Can you please help, how to do it properly

I'm stuck with this code

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  # Test for POST /users
  describe 'POST /users' do
    let(:user) { User.create(email: 'test@mail.ru', password: 'abc123', token: 'anytokenhere') }
    context '#check valid request' do

      before { post 'create', params: user }

      it 'creates a user' do
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(json['email']).to eq('test@mail.ru')
        expect(json['password']).to eq('abc123')
      end

      it 'returns status code 201' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

got the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController POST /users #check valid request creates a user
     Failure/Error: before { post 'create', params: user }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<User:0x0055f95cee9a48>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController POST /users #check valid request returns status code 201
     Failure/Error: before { post 'create', params: user }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<User:0x0055f95cbebbc0>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I recommend you to use https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation to test your controllers. It has simple syntax and at a bonus you get documentation for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you provide `User` model as a params when `Hash` is expected.

This is an example of a post request to `/users` that works:

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  # Test for POST /users
  describe 'POST /users' do
    let(:user) { User.last }

    context '#check valid request' do
      before { post 'create', params: { user: { email: 'test@mail.ru', password: 'abc123', token: 'anytokenhere' } } }

      it 'creates a user' do
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(user.email).to eq('test@mail.ru')
      end

      it 'returns status code 201' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're so fast. It works. As I understand line ``` let(:user) { User.last } ``` is optional, everything works just fine without it.

Comment: `let(:user) { User.last }` is to get the last user (just created) and verify its email. But, certainly it's up to you how to design your code :)